# Javascript toggle state function

Tags: javascript

I have two functions in my js file:

```
function all_opened()
{
    allToggle(true);
}   

function all_closed()
{
   allToggle(false);
}
```

I need both functions called in single function like
`function openclose()`

And my HTML Code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="">Open/Close</a>
```

Comment: kindly explaing allToggle() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
//define some global js variable, for storing the state
var currentStateOpened = true;
function openclose() {
  //check if state is true or false
  if(currentStateOpened) {  //if state is open then close
     allToggle(false);
     currentStateOpened = false; // set the global state to false
  }
  else {
    allToggle(true);
    currentStateOpened = true; // set the global state to true
  }
}
//And
<a href="#" onclick="openclose(); return false;">Open/Close</a>
```

Comment: This is fine but could you guide me if I have one anchor tag like <a href="#" onclick="">Open/Close</a>

Comment: you could pass it in the same way on adding more anchor tags, isnt it..?

Comment: I mean I need only in one anchor tag, Here you 're calling open for one anchor tag and close for another one. Not like that the function should work for one single anchor (i.e, when I click "Open/Close" first time it should open and again if i click it should close )

Comment: Hello sudhir, Please explain us how could we call a single function for a single anchor tag

Comment: It working for open and not working for close i.e., if I click again it says "d is null" and we didn't had d at all in the code. Please help us

Comment: It shows true and when in javascript console it shows d id null again

Comment: Here we need to all the functions, but in the above code we're calling toggle function. Any how, thank you for your support , it worked

Answer (score 1):

You can store the flag which stores your boolean value in the code and check in it the function itself:

```
flag = false;

function allToggle(){
 flag = !flag ? false : true;
 //rest of the code 
}
```

Comment: And could you help me how could i call this in a single anchor tag

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete, cross-browser, and extensible option. Look at the comments in the code for the description.  Feel free to use this in any projects you like.

**CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
a {
 text-decoration: none;
 outline: none;
}
div.TogWrap {
    width: 400px;
    padding: 12px;
}

/* classes .on and .off are for the links */
.off {
    border: 1px solid #bebebe;
    padding: 7px 8px;
    background: #df7623;
    color: #fff;
}
.on {
    border: 1px solid #bebebe;
    padding: 7px 8px;
    background: #bf7623;
    color: #fff;
}

/* classes .hide and .show are used for the content */
.hide {
    display: none;
}
.show {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #bebebe;
    padding: 16px 10px 10px 10px;
    background: #ededed;
}
</style>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* Cross-Browser Event functions (required) */
function addEvent (eventObj, event, codeToExecute) {
    if (eventObj.addEventListener) {
        eventObj.addEventListener(event, codeToExecute, false );
        return true;
    } else if (eventObj.attachEvent) {
        event = "on" + event;
        eventObj.attachEvent(event, codeToExecute);
    } else {
        eventObj['on' + event] = codeToExecute;
    }
}
function cancelEvent(event) {
    if (event.preventDefault) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    } else  {
        event.returnValue = false;
        event.cancelBubble = true;
    }
}


/* The function that does the hide/show */
function toggleIt (thisEl, thisContent) {
        var el = document.getElementById(thisEl);
        var content = document.getElementById(thisContent);
        content.className = "hide"; //initially hide the contents
        el.className = "off"; //and set the links class to off (optional)

        var toggle = function (event) { //capture the event that was triggered
                switch (event.type) { //check if it was a click event
                    case 'click': //if click
                        content.className = content.className === 'hide' ? 'show' : 'hide'; //self explanatory
                        el.className = content.className === 'hide' ? 'off' : 'on'; //self explanatory (optional)
                        break;
                }
                cancelEvent(event); //prevent the link from following the href attribute
            };

         addEvent (el, 'click', toggle); //onclick call the toggle function
    }


/* Set up function */
function initToggles () {

    //Array of IDs for the links that are clicked - add as many as you need
    var allTriggers = [
        'togTrigger1',
        'togTrigger2'
    ];

    //Array of IDs for the content that you want to hide/show - add as many as you need
    var allContents = [
        'content1',
        'content2'
    ];

    var i = 0,  arrLen = allTriggers.length;
    for (i; i < arrLen; i += 1) {
        toggleIt(allTriggers[i], allContents[i]);
    }
}

/*  the same as window.onload */
addEvent (window, 'load', initToggles);
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<!--You can add as many of these as you need. Just follow the same pattern as I have below -->
<div class="TogWrap">
    <a href="#" id="togTrigger1" class="">Open it / Close it</a>
    <p id ="content1" class="togContent">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Mauris magna.
      Suspendisse accumsan elit non tellus. Curabitur eros justo, malesuada
      convallis, sagittis vitae, convallis sit amet, lectus.
    </p>
</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<!--Here is another one following the same pattern-->
<div class="TogWrap">
    <a href="#"  id="togTrigger2" class="">Open it / Close it</a>
    <p  id ="content2" class="togContent">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Mauris magna.
      Suspendisse accumsan elit non tellus. Curabitur eros justo, malesuada
      convallis, sagittis vitae, convallis sit amet, lectus.
    </p>
</div>
```

I hope it helps!  :)